# Loss and Payments

Tags: self-study

I am given that the amount of loss has a two-point mixture cdf, (55% and 45% weightage) which both follow a Gamma distribution. An insurance imposes an ordinary deductible of d and max. covered loss is u.

How can i determine the value of d such that 20% of the losses do not result in a payment?

What are the steps I should take to approach this question? (the Value of the parameters are assumed to be known)

appreciate any help!

Comment: Ummm, compute the value where the CDF is 0.2 ?

Comment: @barrycarter The question concerns *how* to compute that value. It comes down to finding the inverse CDF of a mixture distribution (which has to be done numerically in general).

Comment: @whuber what do you mean by finding the inverse CDF of the mixture distribution? I was given the hint of taking F(x) - (some value)= 0 but i cant figure out what is the "some value"

Comment: It is sometimes called the [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_.28quantile_function.29).  If you're unsure of what a mixture distribution is, then visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures.